# How to use functors instead of functions in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, functor

I have a model called Story:

```
from django.db import models
from api import settings
from core.functions import UploadImage
from .settings import STORY_UPLOAD_PATH

get_story_upload_path = UploadImage(STORY_UPLOAD_PATH)


class Story(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_story_upload_path)
    caption = models.TextField()
    expiration_date = models.DateTimeField()

    import datetime
    import uuid
    import os
```

The behavior for uploading photos is the same for multiple models, thus I decided to make a functor that holds the path to upload to and pass it to the models with common behaviour.

The functor:

```
import datetime
import uuid
import os


class UploadImage:

    def __init__(self, upload_path):
        self.upload_path = upload_path

    def __call__(self, instance, filename):
        filename = f'{datetime.datetime.now()}_{uuid.uuid4()}_{filename}'
        return os.path.join(self.upload_path, instance.username, filename)
```

The serializer class:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from models import Story, ViewedStory


class StorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Story
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'image', 'caption')
        read_only_fields = ('id', )
```

When I try to make migrations, I get this error:

```
Migrations for 'stories':
  stories/migrations/0001_initial.py
    - Create model Story
    - Create model ViewedStory
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 18, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 413, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 354, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 398, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 89, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 190, in handle
    self.write_migration_files(changes)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 227, in write_migration_files
    migration_string = writer.as_string()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 141, in as_string
    operation_string, operation_imports = OperationWriter(operation).serialize()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 99, in serialize
    _write(arg_name, arg_value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 51, in _write
    arg_string, arg_imports = MigrationWriter.serialize(item)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 271, in serialize
    return serializer_factory(value).serialize()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/serializer.py", line 39, in serialize
    item_string, item_imports = serializer_factory(item).serialize()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/serializer.py", line 201, in serialize
    return self.serialize_deconstructed(path, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/serializer.py", line 88, in serialize_deconstructed
    arg_string, arg_imports = serializer_factory(arg).serialize()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/migrations/serializer.py", line 353, in serializer_factory
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Cannot serialize: <core.functions.UploadImage object at 0x7f369fbb27f0>
There are some values Django cannot serialize into migration files.
For more, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/migrations/#migration-serializing
```

Why is this happening and how can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/migrations/#serializing-values):

> Migrations are Python files containing the old definitions of your
> models - thus, to write them, Django must take the current state of
> your models and serialize them out into a file.

This means that Django needs to serialize all things used in the models. Since `get_story_upload_path` is an instance of `UploadImage`, a class you made yourself Django obviously does not know how to serialize it.

The solution to this is also mentioned in the documentation which is to [Add a deconstruct() method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/migrations/#adding-a-deconstruct-method). If all the arguments to the constructor of the class itself are serializable we can simply use the `deconstructible` decorator instead. Also we would need to add an `__eq__` method so that the migration system can know when a new migration needs to be made. Hence you can change the class `UploadImage` as follows so that it can be serialized:

```
from django.utils.deconstruct import deconstructible

@deconstructible
class UploadImage:
    
    def __init__(self, upload_path):
        self.upload_path = upload_path
    
    def __call__(self, instance, filename):
        filename = f'{datetime.datetime.now()}_{uuid.uuid4()}_{filename}'
        return os.path.join(self.upload_path, instance.username, filename)
    
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return isinstance(other, self.__class__) and self.upload_path == other.upload_path
```